# Matrix program, using binding in python to stop/start

Tags: python, loops, matrix, tkinter

I am trying to write a piece of code that will run a simple matrix replica, where it just randomly generate characters and prints them to a screen.

Writing the actual matrix part has been no problem and I am happy with the way I have done it, although I will welcome any suggestions to that part.

But the part I am stuck on is getting it to stop, once it has started.

Basically in pseudocode this is what I'm trying to do

```
IF PRESS == s:
   matrix()
   check press
   IF PRESS == q:
       END matrix()
```

The main difficulty I am getting is checking the key press while running the matrix code.
This is my code at the moment:

```
import tkinter as tk
from random import randint

global event
event=""

box = tk.Tk()

def matrix():
    line =  chr(randint(0,127)) + "\t" + chr(randint(0,127)) + "\t"
          + chr(randint(0,127)) + "\t" + chr(randint(0,127)) + "\t"
          + chr(randint(0,127)) + "\t" + chr(randint(0,127)) + "\t"
          + chr(randint(0,127)) + "\t" + chr(randint(0,127)) + "\t"
          + chr(randint(0,127)) + "\t" + chr(randint(0,127)) + "\t"
    print (line)
    key(event)

def key(event):
    box.focus_set()
    while event.char == "s":
        print("Matrix starting")
        matrix()
    if event.char == "q":
        #stops matrix
        print("Matrix stopped")

box.bind("<Key>", key)
box.mainloop()
```

Hopefully, someone will be able to help me, I have looked on the internet but I can not find what I am looking for.

Also when I have tried changing my code, the GUI has frozen and I am unable to do anything.

Comment: Besides the endless while() issue & key(event) call from matrix(), causing the same, the **.bind()** key-handler assignments could be used in favour of your logic. See below for proposed solution details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You can create the logic based on Tkinter strengths

Added a repeating delay, as you asked in a comment below.

Added a Stateful Control ( `{ nil->[S]tartedSTATE->[Q]uit->nil }` ) to block/avoid nonsense sequences

Added a few Tkinter details.

You might want to limit the scope of **`chr()`** as not all characters in the original range are "*printable*" and you bear a risk of unwanted side-effects.

```
try:
     import Tkinter as tk
     import tkMessageBox
except:
     import tkinter as tk
     import tkinter.messagebox as tkMessageBox

from random import randint

global event                                      # global is possible, designing a Class is better though
event = ""                                        # no need to assign <event>

global box
box = tk.Tk()                                     # Tkinter top-level instance
box.aDelayInMSEC  = 30000                         # .SET an attribute, repeat each 30 sec
box.inStartedSTATE = False                        # .SET an attribute, a stateful control
box.title( "MATRIX Reloaded ... " )               # Tkinter beautifier
box.protocol( 'WM_DELETE_WINDOW', ExitPROCESS )   # [X]-overide ------------------------
box.lift()                                        # GUI make visible

def matrix():
    line =  chr(randint(0,127)) + "\t" + chr(randint(0,127)) + "\t"
          + chr(randint(0,127)) + "\t" + chr(randint(0,127)) + "\t"
          + chr(randint(0,127)) + "\t" + chr(randint(0,127)) + "\t"
          + chr(randint(0,127)) + "\t" + chr(randint(0,127)) + "\t"
          + chr(randint(0,127)) + "\t" + chr(randint(0,127)) + "\t"
    print (line)
    box.after( box.aDelayInMSEC, matrix )         # re-schedule a next round .after()

def StartMATRIX( anEvent ):
    if not box.inStartedSTATE:                    # .IF( not STARTED-already )
        print( "Matrix starting" )                #     .UI
        box.inStartedSTATE = True                 #     .SET state
        matrix()                                  #     .CALL
     pass

def StopMATRIX( anEvent ):
    if box.inStartedSTATE:                        # .IF( was STARTED-before )
        print( "Matrix stopped" )                 #     .UI
        box.inStartedSTATE = False                #     .SET state
        ExitPROCESS()                             #     .CALL
    pass

def ExitPROCESS():                                # MVC-Controller-Part ..
    if tkMessageBox.askokcancel( "Quit GUI", "Do you really wish to quit?" ):
        box.destroy()
    pass

box.bind(       "<KeyPress-s>", StartMATRIX )    # .BIND StartMATRIX()-HANDLER
box.bind( "<Shift-KeyPress-s>", StartMATRIX )    # .BIND StartMATRIX()-HANDLER
box.bind(       "<KeyPress-q>", StopMATRIX )     # .BIND  StopMATRIX()-HANDLER
box.bind( "<Shift-KeyPress-q>", StopMATRIX )     # .BIND  StopMATRIX()-HANDLER

box.mainloop()
```

Comment: Firstly I kind of understand what you are doing in the code, but there are a few things that baffle me. Secondly, I can not run this code as my python says I have no module tkMessageBox, I perhaps should have mentioned that I amusing python 3.3.3 I presume you are using 2.7. Is there a similar module for 3.3?

Answer (score 1):

Your `key` function is called once for each key press event, but inside you have a while loop that never terminates:

```
while event.char == "s": # program gets stuck in this loop as event.char is 
                         # always "s" for this function call
    print("Matrix starting")
    matrix()
```

An `if` statement should suffice to fix the problem:

```
if event.char == "s":
    print("Matrix starting")
    matrix()
if event.char == "q":
    #stops matrix
    print("Matrix stopped")
```

In order to print multiple lines, you should modify your matrix function to use a `for` loop:

```
def matrix():
    for i in range(10):
        line =  chr(randint(0,127)) + "\t" + chr(randint(0,127)) + "\t"
              + chr(randint(0,127)) + "\t" + chr(randint(0,127)) + "\t"
              + chr(randint(0,127)) + "\t" + chr(randint(0,127)) + "\t"
              + chr(randint(0,127)) + "\t" + chr(randint(0,127)) + "\t"
              + chr(randint(0,127)) + "\t" + chr(randint(0,127)) + "\t"
        print (line)
```

You probably don't want matrix to call `key(event)` as this could also get you into an infinite loop

Comment: Yes, but wouldn't that only print one line of the random characters, I want to be constanly printing the random characters which requires a loop. I have seen people using .after(time, event) but I'm unsure how this works

Comment: Sorry I hadn't seen that last part about the for loop, however this still doesn't allow me to interrupt the matrix as it prints. Is it possible for the loop to be checking of the global event has changed?